# How to implement Facebook Login for multiple apps with a custom backend?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I work for a company that has a suite of 5 iOS and 5 Android apps. They all talk to common API we built. We support traditional email/password account creation and login, but we also support Facebook login in parallel. Given the impending Graph API v2.0 changes, I figured this would be a good time to audit our implementation of Facebook Login to bring it up to the latest standards.

What I haven't been able to find in the Facebook Developers portal is a good high-level overview of what we should be doing given our particular circumstances:

- we have multiple mobile apps authenticated with shared accounts
- we use facebook login alongside email/password accounts
- we have custom backend API that all the apps talk to

Here's a simplified walkthrough of our current implementation of FB Login:

1. App prompts user to login with FB (or enter email to login/create account)
2. If user clicks FB button, FB's login magic happens, and the app gets a token which it passes to our API
3. API server calls `/me` using the facebook-php-sdk in order to get the user's graph id, name, and email

   - If we don't get an email back, FB login fails
4. Using the email from FB, we look to see if we already have an account with that email

   - If no account exists with that email, we create a new account using that email and name
5. Once we have a user account (either through creation or lookup), we store the token with that account (unique to the app)
6. At this point we tell the app that the user successfully authenticated

What should we be doing? Should we even bother storing the FB token?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking email for a user on the server, I would have gone for the **userid** (why let those 2-3% of users leave your app just because we can't fetch their email ids).

But anyhow with [**v2**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) in picture, we **can't** get original id of user; the ids returned are app-scoped now!

Now coming to your question.

1. You should save the these **app scoped ids** in your database (may be one-many mapping). And since you are only registering the users with email id that wont be a problem at all.

   *Benefits?* You can access to their profile data easily at any point without any problem with `/<id>?access_token=<app-access-token>`
2. Saving **user access token** don't make any sense to me since it expires in approx 2 hours. Although you can [extend the validity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) of the user access token but you can anytime get a fresh token on client side itself. So store this only if you are doing some stuff/manipulation on server that's important to you.
3. If you are looking for posting [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph) stories or normal [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#publish) on the user's profile when the user's session is not active, you can use the **app access token** to publish.